# Detect if a hudson build is manually or schedule (periodically) invoked

Tags: hudson, schedule

Ive set up deployment in hudson. SVN > Build > copy to production. I need to set up a schedule build to test for build error which is running every hour or so. What I dont want is the schedules builds to deploy to production.
Is it posible to detect, in nant, if the current build is a scheduled build or a manually started build. Or should I create a seperate project for the schedule build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest option is to create a separate job for your scheduled build; you can then keep other artifacts like test results separated (since I assume your scheduled job will be running a different set of tests).

If you're just running the scheduled job to look for build errors, this will also keep the checked-out code that you're building separate from the triggered builds, which will minimize the risk of the production builds getting polluted with artifacts created by the test build.